# VB.NET: How to incrementally replace values in String Array

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

I have a String array with the following values:

```
dim strArray() as string  
dim newValueFor0Index as string = "Z"  
strArray(0) = "A"  
strArray(1) = "B"  
strArray(2) = "C"`
```

what i need is a loop or something to replace the values as such:

```
strArray(0) = "Z"  
strArray(1) = "A"  
strArray(2) = "B"`
```

I then need to add another index to the strArray() which will hold the last value ie:

```
strArray(0) = "Z"  
strArray(1) = "A"  
strArray(2) = "B"  
strArray(3) = "C"`
```

I tried a while loop :

```
while i < Count

    ni++  
    currentArr(ni) = currentArr(i)  
    i++  
end while
```

but this won't work because `i` am using redundant values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array is simply  the wrong collection type to do this.  It is trivial with a list:

```
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    lst.Add("A")
    lst.Add("B")
    lst.Add("C")
    lst.Insert(0, "Z")
```

You can always whack it back to an array, if *really* necessary:

```
    Dim array() As String = lst.ToArray()
```

Comment: the array is coming from a cookie and i am putting it into an array by doing... strArray = cookieValue.split("$")

Comment: also if i do as  you advise won't the values of the list be Z, B, C? when i need it to be Z, A, B, C

Comment: `Dim lst As New List(Of String)(cookieValue.Split("$"c))`.  No, Insert really does insert, not replace.

Comment: what does the c signify here?"$"c

Comment: @kevon: It's a cast to `char`. You might want to turn `Option Strict` to `On`. Will save you headache if it comes to casting.